# Speeding Up Chefspec Run

Tags: rspec, chef-infra, chefspec

I have a lot of cookbooks and they are heavily tested with [ChefSpec](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec). I have more than 800 specs and it has become a problem to run them every time before committing code, because on my machine it takes about 20 minutes to run them. That makes ~0.(6)s per spec, which is not much, but adds up to long amount of time.

Is there any possibility to run ChefSpec/RSpec tests in parallel or somehow else increase speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 4 Jan 2014**: The following idea is now implemented inside ChefSpec (>= 3.1.2). See *Faster Specs* part in [Readme](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec#faster-specs).

================================

This is a **excerpt from an [blogpost](http://dracoater.blogspot.com/2013/12/testing-chef-cookbooks-part-25-speeding.html)** that covers this topic with some more details.

[RSpec allows to extend modules with your own methods](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-0/docs/helper-methods/define-helper-methods-in-a-module) and the idea is to write method similar to *let*, but which will cache the results across examples too. Create a *spec_helper.rb* file somewhere in your Chef project and add the following lines there:

```
module SpecHelper
  @@cache = {}
  def shared( name, &block )
    location = ancestors.first.metadata[:example_group][:location]
    define_method( name ) do
      @@cache[location + name.to_s] ||= instance_eval( &block )
    end
  end

  def shared!( name, &block )
    shared name, &block
    before { __send__ name }
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.extend SpecHelper
end
```

Values from *@@cache* are never deleted, and you can use same names with this block, so I also use location of the usage, which looks like that: "./cookbooks/my_cookbook/spec/default_spec.rb:3". Now change `let( :chef_run )` into `shared( :chef_run )` in your specs:

```
describe "example::default" do
  shared( :chef_run ) { ChefSpec::ChefRunner.new.converge described_recipe }
  [...]
end
```

And when running the tests you will now have to include the spec_helper.rb too:

```
rspec --include ./relative/path/spec_helper.rb cookbooks/*/spec/*_spec.rb
```